# Custom date sort in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery datatable and my html table's one of the column contains dates.

So how can we write custom date sort function? It is by default sorting as String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use custom sort functionality provided in jquery datatables.
Use this link:
http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

Comment: Wooooooooooooooo ... why it didn't clicked to me. It's sorting perfectly. You are great.